# Poor service performance on IIS when rapidly blasting simultaneous connections

Tags: c#, performance, iis, servicestack

I have developed a fairly simple web service that runs on ServiceStack. I have deployed it to an IIS instance, and now I'm load-testing it.

For some reason, I'm seeing really poor performance. As the number of simultaneous requests increases, the median elapsed time for each request rises rapidly, from about 70ms (due to network latency) all the way up to 5 seconds and more when I start running multiple simultaneous requests. What's odd is that some requests still complete in 70ms, it's just the majority of them get much slower.

My service is not very demanding; and, in fact, when I check the utilization of the machine where IIS is running, I see that it's memory use, CPU use, and network bandwidth use are negligible -- throughout the entire test. So, what's going on ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: There is way too little information for us to help you. You need to use a profiler to see what happens

Comment: @AK_: which profiler would you recommend ? As I said, the CPU usage on the machine is negligible, so I'm not sure if a profiler will tell me anything useful. Yes, it will show me the places where my code is spending most of its time, but the problem is, it's not actually spending all that much time on anything.

Comment: Does the service code block when servicing a request? Sync io anywhere?

Comment: The visual studio pro/ultimate versions come with a profiler, JetBrains have a pretty good one, but personally i like RedGates: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

Comment: Just a suggestion. Could it be due to limited number of simultaneous threads in iis?